# How to make a login view with Couchbase + Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, couchbase, xamarin.forms, sample, couchbase-lite

I was searching for a sample but couldn't find any. Anybody know where I can found an example source code for this? If it is with Xamarin.Forms, that would be great.

I was doing some simple experiments with Couchbase, using the component for Xamarin:
https://components.xamarin.com/view/couchbase-lite-net

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are some nice guides here: http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/web-services/authentication/ not on Couchbase specifically, but you could follow the same renderer process.

Comment: Is your question related to Couchbase Lite?  Are you trying to store login information with it?

Comment: @JamesMontemagno Thank you, I will check it out!

Comment: @borrrden Yes in part, it is related to Couchbase Lite. Basically I would like to check if username and password matches in database, so the user can login.